# SBT how to add unmanaged jars to subproject tests?

Tags: scala, jar, dependencies, sbt

I have an SBT multiproject structure, but for some reason sbt does not recognize the unmanaged jar when tests are run. The objective is to have a stub subproject without an actual implementation and add this as a `"Provided"` dependency to the Main class, it should detect the jars in the `/lib` folder when provided. The actual implementation in the `.jar` file simply prints a random string.

Here is the project structure.

```
./MainClass
./MainClass/lib/printsomethingexample_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./MainClass/src/test/scala/Main.scala
./MainClass/src/main/scala/Main.scala
./stub/lib/printsomethingexample_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
./stub/src/main/scala/test/stub/Example.scala
./build.sbt
```

File main/scala/Main.scala

```
import test.stub.Example

object Main extends App {
  Example.printSomething()
}
```

File test/scala/Main.scala

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec._
import test.stub.Example

class Main extends AnyFlatSpec {

  "Unmanaged jar" should "work" in {
    Example.printSomething()
  }

}
```

scala/test/stub/Example.scala:

```
package test.stub

object Example {
  def printSomething(): Unit = ???
}
```

build.sbt:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "stubExample"
  ).aggregate(MainClass, stub)

lazy val stub = project
  .in(file("stub"))
  .settings(
    name := "stub"
  )

lazy val MainClass = project
  .in(file("MainClass"))
  .settings(
    name := "MainClass",
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.14" % Test,
  ).dependsOn(`stub` % Provided)
```

When I run `sbt "MainClass/runMain Main"` it finds the unmanaged jars as expected and prints the string, but when I run `sbt "MainClass/test"` I get the following error:

```
[info] Main:
[info] Unmanaged jar
[info] - should work *** FAILED ***
[info]   scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

Does anyone understand why the jars are not found?

*** EDIT ***
Here is the output of `sbt "MainClass/runMain Main"`

```
▶ sbt "MainClass/runMain Main"
[info] welcome to sbt 1.6.2 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0_312)
[info] loading global plugins from /Users/riccardo/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading project definition from /Users/riccardo/Documents/Projects/stubExample/project
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to stubExample (in build file:/Users/riccardo/Documents/Projects/stubExample/)
[info] running Main
Printed Something
```

The `.jar` has an implementation of `test.stub.Example#printSomething` (It is a different project)

```
package test.stub

object Example {
  def printSomething(): Unit = println("Printed Something")
}
```

My expectation is that since the stub subproject is marked as `Provided` it should use the `printSomething` implementation from the jar in the classpath instead of the stub subproject, the stub subproject was marked as `Provided` and would expect it to be excluded from the classpath (maybe I don't understand how `Provided` works).

This behavior happens when running the main class as shown above, it uses the `printSomething` from the classpath in `lib/printsomethingexample_2.13-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` instead of using the stub that is not implemented. In my real life scenario, I need the dependency on the stub subproject.

If I remove the `dependsOn` the `sbt test` step works, but the project wouldn't compile without the unmanaged jars in the `/lib` folder, hence why we use a stub subproject as dependecy, just to make the project compile.

Comment: "implementation is missing" because it uses your `test.stub.Example` code with `???`, not because it doesn't find the jar. what happens if you remove the `.dependsOn(`stub` % Provided)` part in `build.sbt`?
Also, please add output of `show MainClass/unmanagedJars`.

Comment: @laughedelic thank you for your comment, I added an EDIT section that answers your questions, hope it helps.